# Random process and predictability

Tags: random, philosophy

We are familiar with random process. For example the result of tossing a coin is considered a random process. So rolling a dice. In this logical scheme, the realization of a random process is unpredictable. In the reality, if we could consider the initial conditions of the differential equations describing the motion of the coin or the dice we could forecast the result of the process. Is it possible to have a 'pure' random process or better an absolutely unpredictable random event? Obviously this would imply an effect without cause.
Could this involve logical contradictions?
Thanks.

Comment: See [Philosophical Issues in Quantum Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-issues/): in the quantum world, the unpredictability of the future state of a process is not due to our "lack of knowledge", but is an "intrinsic" fueature of the process.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: that means there is an effect without cause. Or maybe we don't still know the real cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all the physical processes that I have encountered at work (and indeed, I have not ever done quantum physics and such), the randomness has just been a model that neatly encapsulates what could be found by integrating deterministic equations with infinite computational power and memory.  As in the last paragraph of this answer.

https://www.quora.com/Is-The-Brownian-motion-truly-random-and-how-does-that-tie-in-with-a-large-percentage-of-the-scientific-community-on-the-side-of-a-deterministic-universe-and-hence-the-popular-view-of-the-illusion-of-free-will